# How to describe a multipart response using OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, multipart, openapi

I have a service that creates a multipart file containing:

- a data byte array that represents an image buffer
- a JSON that represents information about the image (coord, format, etc.)

Is it possible to model this custom response in an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition, using YAML?

Answer (score 12):

Multipart responses can be described using OpenAPI 3.0, but not OpenAPI 2.0 (fka Swagger 2.0).

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            multipart/mixed: # <-- Content-Type of the response
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  # Part 1 - application/octet-stream
                  file:  # <-- part name
                    type: string
                    format: binary
                  # Part 2 - application/json
                  metadata:  # <-- part name
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      foo:
                        type: string
                        example: bar
                    required:
                      - foo

              # Optional, see https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#encoding-object
              encoding:
                file:
                  ...
                metadata:
                  ...
```

The optional [`encoding`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#encoding-object) key can be used to override the `Content-Type` for subparts or add headers for subparts (e.g. `Content-Disposition`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try with that !

Comment: Hi!
The solution you propose doesn't work. Cf. The document you link to:
"The encoding object SHALL only apply to requestBody objects when the media type is multipart or application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: As I understand RFC2046, Multipart/mixed doesn't have a dedicated order of parts. how are you able to define the `schema` parts and how are the media types defined for those parts? As mentioned by @cydouzo, the `encoding` object is only valid for `requestBody`

Comment: the `name` property is not required when `multipart/mixed` is defined.  The `name` property is only required for `multipart/form-data`